# Did people use the Shem hameforash during the time of the First Temple?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, shemos-sacred-names

Many people (especially the kings of Judah) seemed to use the suffix 'yahu' in their names, which seems to be related to the actual four-letter name. Are there any sources on this? Did the Neviim of the First Temple period use the Shem HaMeforash?

Answer (score 0):

there is a reason for this, on patach eliyahu(eliyahu's opening/introduction to the torah secrets):

on song of songs it says:
אֲנִ֥י יְשֵׁנָ֖ה וְלִבִּ֣י עֵ֑ר ק֣וֹל ׀ דּוֹדִ֣י דוֹפֵ֗ק פִּתְחִי־לִ֞י אֲחֹתִ֤י רַעְיָתִי֙ יֽוֹנָתִ֣י תַמָּתִ֔י שֶׁרֹּאשִׁי֙ נִמְלָא־טָ֔ל קְוֻצּוֹתַ֖י רְסִ֥יסֵי לָֽיְלָה

so what does it mean my head is filled with tal?
טָ֔ל
also look at the cantillation mark above for a clue , and the nikud vowel marks,
as they tell a lot

so tal is detailed in here on Isaiah prophet:
כִּ֣י טַ֤ל אוֹרֹת֙ טַלֶּ֔ךָ וָאָ֖רֶץ רְפָאִ֥ים תַּפִּֽיל
so tal means light , that bring up the dead to live,
it isn't exactly about the physical lives we live,
but you can live physically but still be considered as dead,
because you are attaching/connecting  with the side of impurity
they are called death ,
as it says on משלי:
רַ֭גְלֶיהָ יֹרְד֣וֹת מָ֑וֶת ,
the legs of shechina from world atzilut , drop down to where death is,
(the worlds of separation , are called death , in opposite to atzilut which is devine: and on atzilut and above where there is devinity it says: לֹ֖א יְגֻרְךָ֣ רָֽע
but below the devine there is death, because there is a reality of evil in there the more you go down, and the deepest lowest part of it is this physical world)

so all that related to evil and impurity and ego and separation and darkness, are called death,
and the opposite of it is called life , the side of holiness , purity and altruism and unity and free love and happiness,

so when one person lives , he can connect to life or connect to death,
so the lights of tal , can awaken a living person that is connected to the side of death,
to reconnect him with the side of life while living

also these divine lights are related to awakening the resurrection

so we continue to look into the above sentence meaning:

and land of Rephaim will fall,

land means the
measurement of malchut(kingship) / מידת המלכות

המידה הזאת היא אחת מ10 מאמרות בראשית
and king david , and shechina are related to this measurement of kingship

but above land is not about the holy shechina / divine residence, but the opposite of her, related to impurity
because there was:

נפילים , ענקים, רפאים
the nephilim were 2 angels,
that went down to this physical world,
and had babies with women,
they made, og king of bashan , and shichon ,
both of them were giants, because there were sons of angels,
they lived many years and survived the מבול, they where on noach ark,
but the generation of children of theirs after that ,
is called rephaim,
because they were
נרפו מהקדושה העליונה,
לשון ריפיון
וכל דור מאלה , ירד עוד ועוד מהקדושה שלו

so land is synonim to: measurement of kingship ,(whether if related to side of purity or side of evil , it's a general term), land doesn't mean a physical place in this sentence

so land of repahim ,
means the land of evil influence , the makes people saggy/slack from working hard toward connecting to life and holiness/purity

so why this land attachment/influence will fall , when there is resurrection?
because on Isaiah prophet, it says:
בִּלַּ֤ע הַמָּ֙וֶת֙ לָנֶ֔צַח
on the day of (salvation of evil/revelation of divinity)

so after this introduction we can continue , to detail what is the meaning of tal lights:
on eliyahu opening to the secrets, he tells that tal is gimetria of the first part of the holy explicit name,
in this way
you take the first 3 letters of the name,
and convert it from simple letter , to filled letter,
you can fill it on couple of ways depending on the nikud you want,
but on the holy name that is called tal,
the letters filled with the letter aleph א ,

so י becomes יו"ד
when it filled
because there is no place for א in there,
but the second letter,
ה becomes ה"א , not ה"ה  , and not ה"י....
so it's filled with א where possible

so you have the first 3 letters filled:
equals in gimatria  to tal gimatria value
the first letter

י קשורה למידת החכמה

ה" קשורה למידת  הבינה
"

ו קשור למידת התפארת

so this describes the path of divine light of infinity from god , how it navigated down into the shechina and then from atzilut(אורות) to the worlds of seperation(כלים)
and then the abundance of lights goes down to this world too and lights it with life power

and this is called tal

many added this "tal" prefix to there names , in order to connect with the divine lights/or ha-ganuz , in order to affects this abundance to others around, like aluma אלומה של אור around , so people around them will be connected to this power of life , from god

אז שמו את הקידומת הזאת בשם שלהם
כדי להתחבר אל כח האור
כדי להשפיע לכלים סביב

במקום להתחבר לכח הכלים והרצון לקבל לעצמנו בלבד
אז להתחבר לרצון להשפיע לטובת הכלל
ולהקרין תקווה וחיוביות לאחרים סביב

btw, this is the full explained and detailed , Eliyahu's intduction to the wisdom of secrets

https://www.docdroid.net/P6Vg44Z/document

Comment: on their time they could use it , only cohen at the temple, because they didn't had the impurity of death, they had red cow to purify them from this impurity, but on this generation we don't have red cow ash , to do it , so we can't use holy names or angel names , and of course , on every generation/time , when it was used it wasn't used for ego and selfish stuff , but only used for holy purpose , altruism and saving many many lifes , but usually even when they could use it they wouldn't, becayse they didn't wanted to change the natural order of thinks , as the ההנהגה האלוקית, is more correct